# Add points to path

Tags: d3.js

I'm drawing a simple path through some arbitrary data points and I want to shape it into 'spikes' by adding points offset 20px on X on each side of each existing data point and those new points a value of 0 and then draw the path through them.

I've tried splicing in points in the data but that didn't work with the linear scales.

```
    var data = d3.range(13).map(function(){return Math.random()*10})
    var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 12]).range([50, w-20]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([50, h-70]);

    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d,i) { return x(i);})
      .y(function(d) { return y(d);})
      .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

    var path = svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", line(data))
      .attr("stroke", "white")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2")
      .attr("fill", "none");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would preprocess your dataset to generate x and y values that would draw what you need, which would work well with a linear scale.

You can calculate the value to add/minus from the x value using the scale's invert() function, which takes a range value and returns what domain value would give that range.

Then using that domain 'padding' value, create 3 data points: first, the x value minus the padding value, with a y value of 0. Second, the original data point. Third, the x value plus the padding value, with a y value of 0

The line function needs to be updated to work with the new dataset. See snippet for details.

```js
    
    let w = 500
    let h = 250
    let m = 50
    
    var svg = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w + m + m)
      .attr("height", h + m + m)
    
    var g = svg.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate("+ m + "," + m +")")

    var data = d3.range(13).map(function(){return Math.random()*10})
    
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
     .domain([0, 12]).range([0, w]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
     .domain([0, 10])
     .range([h, 0]);
    
    var lineData = []
    
    //if you want 20px, calculate the value needed to +/- to the x value
    let padding = x.invert(10)
    
    data.forEach(function(d, i){
      lineData.push({"x": (i - padding), "y": 0 })
      lineData.push({"x": i, "y": d })
      lineData.push({"x": (i + padding), "y": 0 })
    })
    
    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d,i) { return x(d.x);})
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.y);})
      .curve(d3.curveLinear);

    var path = g.append("path")
      .attr("d", line(lineData))
```

```css
 path {
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 2;
      fill: none;
      stroke-linecap: round
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```